# How can I set the include path in CodeIgniter Framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

How can I set the include path in CodeIgniter Framework?

And what's the default value?

Comment: Why do you need an include path?

Answer (score 5):

```
  ini_set('include_path',   ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH .'libraries');
```

you can read full wiki example - how to add include path for Pear Library

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PEAR_integration/

Answer (score 2):

Include paths have nothing to do with your framework: they're server settings, you can edit them via php.ini, .htacces or using `ini_set("include_path", "/path/relative/to/webroot")`.

Also, it's kind of weird to directly use include() in such a framework: isn't that what helpers and libraries are for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the default is PHP's [**`include_path`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

And, to change the `include_path`, you can either :

- Edit your `php.ini` file,
- Or use the [**`set_include_path()`**](https://www.php.net/set_include_path) function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the `include path` mean **here**. If you mean BASEPATH or APPPATH, they are set in index.php in the root directory.

Comment: That is what happens when people learn CI instead of learning php, lol.